# Postgresql multiple tables with same foreign key unique constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have following tables on PostgreSQL 9.4

```
CREATE TABLE "user" (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    email CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
    password CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "dealer" (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "user" (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

CREATE TABLE "affiliate" (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "user" (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

Is it possible to force `user_id` value to be unique across tables `dealer` and `affiliate`?

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to enforce a constraint that allows a user_id to be in either dealer or affiliate, but not both?

Comment: @PeterHeadland Yes, essentially a user can be either a dealer or affiliate, never both.

Comment: Did saw your (now removed) comment and decided to expand my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are different setups to use for inheritance in SQL and for this you could just use an integer column `type` in the table `user` that marks the type of the user and would reference to table `user_type (id,name)` that would have the values `1,dealer` and `2,affiliate`:

```
CREATE TABLE user_type (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, --could be SERIAL
  name text
);
INSERT INTO user_type VALUES (1,'dealer'), (2, 'affiliate');

CREATE TABLE "user" (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    email CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
    password CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
    user_type INTEGER REFERENCES user_type NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE(id,user_type)
);
```

This in itself wouldn't force uniqueness across tables so after implementing this you would have the following options:

- **Drop the tables `dealer` and `affiliate`** - you won't need them if you rely on the type field to see which one the user is.

If you have to keep those inherited tables you can:

- **Use triggers** - these triggers check the uniqueness and would be actived on `INSERT` or `UPDATE`
- Another (a bit clumsy) solution: **add `user_type` field to both subtables** like this:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE "dealer" (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  user_type INTEGER NOT NULL  DEFAULT 1 check (user_type = 1),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id,user_type) REFERENCES "user"(id,user_type) ON DELETE RESTRICT
  );

  CREATE TABLE "affiliate" (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  user_type INTEGER NOT NULL  DEFAULT 2 check (user_type = 2),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id,user_type) REFERENCES "user"(id,user_type) ON DELETE RESTRICT
  );
  ```

  The checks and foreign keys together make sure you cannot have both types of user in the main table. Note that `user_id` might be used as the `PRIMARY KEY` in the subtables too. Currently a row in `user` might have several `dealer` rows linked to it so at least you might want to set `user_id` foreign keys in subtables as `UNIQUE`.